# process.env.FOO transformed into {}.FOO and throwing error "expected expression, got "."

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gatsby, rollupjs

I wrote a TypeScript module that interacts with a specific RESTful API. The module never refers to `process.env` anywhere (target is browser, possibly Node down the line as well).

I use Rollup to transpile to a single JS file. From there, going into Node and `require('./build/index')` is successful, and I can even run the functions and get expected results. So Rollup itself appears to work.

But the file contains many references to things like `process.env.DEBUG`. (I suspect Rollup is doing something to create loggers that can work in both Node and browser.)

Now I import this into a Gatsby UI project that will need to connect to the API using this module:

```
import { api } from 'my-api'
api.someApiCall()
```

Problem is that when Gatsby compiles all this (using Webpack?) into `commons.js` (some big JS file with a lot of combined code from different libraries, including my API module), it appears to transform the module's `process.env.DEBUG` (for example) into `{}.DEBUG`. Then the browser complains that "expected expression, got '.'". Which makes sense. You cannot access `{}.DEBUG`. It would have to be `({}).DEBUG` or `const o = {}; o.DEBUG`.

Now I have been off in the world of other languages for a while. Rollup is fairly new to me. Gatsby is *very* new to me. What is the way forward? Do I tell Rollup via a config to replace `process.env` with `({})` so that way ? But then that precludes the library from ever being used in Node.js and taking advantage of process.env.

Do I need to change something about Gatsby to have it replace `process.env` with `({})`?

**Edit** For example, here is some output showing up in my browserin `commons.js`:

```js
function save(namespaces) {
  if (null == namespaces) {
    // If you set a process.env field to null or undefined, it gets cast to the
    // string 'null' or 'undefined'. Just delete instead.
    delete {}.DEBUG;
  } else {
    {}.DEBUG = namespaces;
  }
}

/**
 * Load `namespaces`.
 *
 * @return {String} returns the previously persisted debug modes
 * @api private
 */

function load() {
  return {}.DEBUG;
}
```

In my module, those are `process.env.DEBUG`.

**Edit 2** I've also tried putting a gatsby-node.js containing this:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  plugins,
  actions,
}) => {
  const { setWebpackConfig } = actions;

  setWebpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      plugins.define({
        'process.env': "({})",
        '{}.DEBUG': '({}).DEBUG',
      })
    ]
  })
}
```

No effect.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Whatever part of your toolchain exactly is doing these replacements, it should never generate invalid code - file an issue. (Also ideally it would not replace `process.env` by distinct object literals, but with references to a shared object).

Comment: Based on some googling, it seems like webpack does some sort of `eval()` under the hood, and when it `eval(process.env)` that becomes `{}` in the code as Gatsby+Webpack is munging all the code. There are other people with the same issue, but the workarounds seem not to work for Gatsby, just pure Webpack. Can't seem to triangulate where the `eval` is taking place in the Gatsby build process, so I can't prevent it.

In the meantime, I have my separate TypeScript module w/rollup specifically generating browser-only code, which generates zero uses of `process.env`. Temp fix. Suboptimal.